Can a DFA have no transitions to just accept the empty word?
Online, I only find DFAs that have two states and one transition to accept: $\{ \epsilon \}$, so one state is accepting and the other acts as a dead state where everything that is not the empty word will lead to.
However, a transition function can be partial for DFAs, so could you not just define a DFA that consists of a single accepting state and zero transitions? Or does that not work because that would be also accepting $\{\}$?

If the single accepting state is also an initial state, then yes, it is a valid DFA to accept $\{\varepsilon\}$.
Adding another state that acts as a sink for the other words is necessary to create a complete automaton which is sometimes used as the definition of a DFA.

So if you use a single state that is initial and accepting, it would work and the 'sink state' just assumed to be there?
So drawing a single state automaton with no transitions is equivalent to drawing a two state automaton with one transition that takes any non-empty string character to the non-accepting state?

Yes, but if you want the automaton to be complete, you also have to add a transition from the sink state to itself for each character.
